# How to send a json file from one ios phone to another?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to send one json file stored on the first Iphone, to second Iphone, without internet connection. I want to use document directory for maintain safety files, but i don't know to send this information and how to stored information. Before saving the file in the document directory I have to save it somewhere else and then move it

Comment: Where you save the file on the device is up to you, but you will need to use some other protocol such as multipeer connectivity to actually share the file. You could also consider just making the file available via a UIActionSheet and the users can use airdrop

Comment: you can share it UIActivityController I guess

Comment: UIActovityController for send file to another phone ?

Comment: yes with air drop?

Comment: UIActivityController has air drop sharing option so you can share without internet connection?